# Unable to clear or set x-forwarded-proto using more_clear_input_headers in nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

So here is my setup

https -> AWB ALB -> ingress-nginx -> sonarqube

The x-forwarded-proto header received at the ingress and subsequently sonarqube is http because ssl offloads at the ALB. I want to change x-forwarded-proto to https. So far I have tried

- `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;`  which results in the header being appended as `"x-forwarded-proto": "http, https"` which is not what I require.
- `more_clear_input_headers "x-forwarded-proto"` in an attempt to clear the header which does not work for this and many other (works for `user-agent` though)
- `more_set_input_headers "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"` which does not update the header value for this and many other headers but works for adding some custom headers.

I am using the kubernetes ingress-nginx

Why is it that I am unable to clear or set some headers but not all, especially the `X-Forwarded-*`

Answer (score -2):

The X-Forwarded-Proto request header helps you identify the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) that a client used to connect to your load balancer. Your server access logs contain only the protocol used between the server and the load balancer; they contain no information about the protocol used between the client and the load balancer. To determine the protocol used between the client and the load balancer, use the X-Forwarded-Proto request header. Elastic Load Balancing stores the protocol used between the client and the load balancer in the X-Forwarded-Proto request header and passes the header along to your server.

Your application or website can use the protocol stored in the X-Forwarded-Proto request header to render a response that redirects to the appropriate URL.

The X-Forwarded-Proto request header takes the following form:

X-Forwarded-Proto: originatingProtocol

The following example contains an X-Forwarded-Proto request header for a request that originated from the client as an HTTPS request:
X-Forwarded-Proto: https

For more information please refer to this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html).